# Skip specific observations when using row_number() - R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm essentially after a "next" statement which I can use within a dplyr ifelse statement, although other R alternatives are also welcome.

Here's the code so far:

```
df1 <- data%>%
  arrange(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)%>%
  group_by(Var1)%>%
  distinct(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)%>%
  mutate(Var6 = ifelse(Var4 == "COMPLETE", row_number(), row_number()+1))
```

the output is (relevant version)

```
  | Var4         | Var6         |
  | ------------ | -------------|
  | COMPLETE     | 1            |
**| INCOMPLETE   | 3            |**
  | COMPLETE     | 3            |
  | COMPLETE     | 4            |
  | COMPLETE     | 5            |
**| INCOMPLETE   | 7            |**
  | COMPLETE     | 7            |
  | COMPLETE     | 8            |
  | COMPLETE     | 9            |
```

the intended output is

```
  | Var4         | Var6         |
  | ------------ | -------------|
  | COMPLETE     | 1            |
**| INCOMPLETE   | 2            |**
  | COMPLETE     | 2            |
  | COMPLETE     | 3            |
  | COMPLETE     | 4            |
**| INCOMPLETE   | 5            |**
  | COMPLETE     | 5            |
  | COMPLETE     | 6            |
  | COMPLETE     | 7            |
```

In summary, my goal is that when **Var4 == INCOMPLETE** I am able to ignore that row and continue with **row_number()**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
setDT(df1)[Var4 == "COMPLETE", Var6 := .I]
df1 %>% 
   fill(Var6, .direction = "updown")
```

-output

```
        Var4 Var6
1:   COMPLETE    1
2: INCOMPLETE    2
3:   COMPLETE    2
4:   COMPLETE    3
5:   COMPLETE    4
6: INCOMPLETE    5
7:   COMPLETE    5
8:   COMPLETE    6
9:   COMPLETE    7
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Var6 = na_if(replace(Var4, Var4 == "COMPLETE", 
     seq_len(sum(Var4 == "COMPLETE"))), "INCOMPLETE")) %>%
   fill(Var6, .direction = "updown")
        Var4 Var6
1   COMPLETE    1
2 INCOMPLETE    2
3   COMPLETE    2
4   COMPLETE    3
5   COMPLETE    4
6 INCOMPLETE    5
7   COMPLETE    5
8   COMPLETE    6
9   COMPLETE    7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var4 = c("COMPLETE", "INCOMPLETE", "COMPLETE", 
"COMPLETE", "COMPLETE", "INCOMPLETE", "COMPLETE", "COMPLETE", 
"COMPLETE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumsum` and `replace` or `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(var6 = cumsum(Var4=='COMPLETE') %>%
                      replace(., Var4=='INCOMPLETE', . +1))

#OR

df1 %>% mutate(var6 = cumsum(Var4=='COMPLETE') %>% 
                      case_when(Var4=='INCOMPLETE', ~ . +1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering. I couldn't make your answers work but it helped me to work this out:

```
    df1 <- data%>%
      arrange(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)%>%
      group_by(Var1)%>%
      distinct(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)%>%
      mutate(Var6 = cumsum(Var4=='COMPLETE') %>%
               ifelse(Var4=='INCOMPLETE', .+1, .))
```